# make use of a script

Tags: python, google-maps, web-scraping

I'm try to make use of a python script that has already been written and it is available via https://code.google.com/p/webscraping/source/browse/download.py It should help me download some information from google maps using GoogleMaps() class and geocode() function. , but every time I can't call the class and function. I put `GoogleMaps(D).geocode("lund", 5, True, 1, "en")` and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 1061, in <module>
    GoogleMaps(D).geocode("lund", 5, True, 1, "en")
NameError: name 'D' is not defined
```

How exactly I should call the function?

Comment: `self.D` seems to be an instance of `Download`. What error do you get?

Comment: well, I get error from get(). The problem is I don't know how to call the call and function here

Comment: Please edit your question and paste a *complete traceback* of the error you get so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined any variable named `D`. From what I can see after a quick look at the script you linked to, you need to instantiate a `Download` first, then pass that to `GoogleMaps()`.

Example:

`d = Download()
result = GoogleMaps(d).geocode("lund", 5, True, 1, "en")`

Comment: thanks, I need to install some modules first and then I'll let you know about the result

Comment: Now there is an error "ImportError: No module named adt" but I can't find a module named "adt" is it a module ?

Comment: Strange. Please post a traceback again.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 37, in <module>
    import adt
ImportError: No module named adt

Comment: Did you write the test1.py file?

Comment: copy and past exactly as the link I gave you in the post

Comment: It seems to be a module containing various types of data structures. I couldn't find anything on where to find it, maybe it is included somewhere in the webscraping project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65581/discussion-between-f-ashouri-and-mezgrman).